# Integral representation of directional derivative

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We consider the Dirichlet problem
$$
 \begin{array}{c}
 \Delta\psi(x) + v(x)\psi(x) = 0, \;\;\; x \in D \\
 \psi|_{\partial{D}} = f
  \end{array}
$$
in some bounded region $D$ with smooth boundary $\partial D$. The operator $\Phi$ is defined by formula
$$
 \Phi[f](x) = \frac{\partial \psi(x)}{\partial \nu}, \;\;\; x \in \partial D
$$
where $\nu$ is an exterior normal to $D$ in $x$. I try to show constructively that $\Phi$ is an integral operator with Shwartz's kernel $\Phi(x,y), \; x,y \in \partial D$ and
$$
 \Phi(x,y) = \frac{\partial G(x,y)}{\partial \nu_x \partial \nu_y} ,\;\;\; x,y \in \partial D
$$
where $G(x,y)$ is a Green function for considered PDE:
$$
 \begin{array}{c}
   (\Delta_x - v)G(x,y) = \delta(x-y), \;\;\; x,y \in D\\
  G(x,y) = 0, \;\;\; x \in \partial D, \;\;\; y \in D
  \end{array}
$$
What should I do to receive this representation? Maybe I can find the demonstration in some book?